# Xampp + Wordpress Rest API (401 code: rest_cannot_create)

Tags: wordpress, xampp, postman, wordpress-rest-api

**What do i want to acheive?**
- i want to create a post for my custom post type with the wordpress rest api

**What Api route is having problems?**
- http://localhost/proftaak/wp-json/wp/v2/mycustomposttype

**What http method are you using?**
- **POST** method (post = not working, get = working)

**What Local apache server are you using?**
- I'm using xampp as local apache + mysql server.

**What have i done?**
- I created a new custom post type. see here:

```php
add_action('init', 'create_custom_post_types');
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_default_post_types');

function create_custom_post_types()
{
    // Apparaten (requests)
    register_post_type('apparaten', [
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'label' => 'Apparaten',
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-smartphone',
        'capabilities' => array(
            'create_posts' => false
        ),
        'labels' => [
            'singular_name' => 'Apparaat'
        ],
    ]);
}

function remove_default_post_types()
{
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
}
```

i've set my custom post type to show_in_rest to true because i want to use it.
But if i do a post in postman to the url i get this:
[image]
i've researched a lot but can't find a solution.
any one an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution

for custom post types you need to create your own rest api route (wp rest api only adds a GET request).
you can do that by using the "register_rest_route" function from wordpress.

Comment: I am new to WordPress, can you please explain the process?